# Unable to cover catch block code coverage

Tags: java, junit

I am not able to cover below HttpClientErrorException catch block in Junit code coverage. How can I do this?

### code

```
@Autowired
private ExceptionHandlerService errorHandler;
public CartResponse callUpdateCart(AddToCartRequest request) {
        String url = Utils.formatHttpUrl(cartbaseUrl, CART_UPDATE_CART);
        try {

            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request);
            JsonNode jsonNode = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, JsonNode.class);
            if (jsonNode.has(Constants.CONTENT) && !jsonNode.path(Constants.CONTENT).path(Constants.PAYLOAD).isMissingNode()) {
                    jsonNode = jsonNode.path(Constants.PAYLOAD).get(Constants.PAYLOAD);
            } else {
                errorHandler.error(ErrorMessages.EPO_VALIDATEQ_ERROR_08, jsonNode);
            }
            
            return JsonService.getObjectFromJson(jsonNode, CartResponse.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            errorHandler.error(ErrorMessages.EPO_VALIDATEQ_ERROR_08, e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            return null;
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorMessages.EPO_SYSTEM_ERROR, e.getMessage(), url);
        }
    }
```

### ExceptionHandlerService

```
@Override
    public void error(ResolvableErrorEnum error, String responseBody) {
        JsonNode response = JsonService.getObjectFromJson(responseBody, JsonNode.class);
        if (null != response && null != response.get(Constants.ERROR)) {
            ServiceError serviceError = JsonService.getObjectFromJsonNode(response.get(Constants.ERROR), ServiceError.class);
            error(error, serviceError.getErrorId(), serviceError.getMessage());
        }
        
        throw new ServiceException(error);
    }
```

### junit

```
@Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void test_callUpdateCart_Exception() throws IOException {
        AddToCartRequest req = createAddToCartRequest();

        String responseBodyStr = "{\"error\":{\"errorId\":\"Service-I-1003\",\"message\":\"Error returned from downstream system.\",\"traceCode\":\"CART;400\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"400\",\"message\":\"400 Bad Request\"},{\"code\":\"DTV_CAT_ERR_002\",\"message\":\"Error in getting response from catalog.\",\"traceCode\":\"CART;400\"}]}}\r\n";
        byte[] body = responseBodyStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        HttpClientErrorException e = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "BAD REQUEST", body,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<HttpEntity<?>>any(), Mockito.eq(JsonNode.class)))
                .thenThrow(e);
        client.callUpdateCart(req);
    }
```

### error

[image]

Comment: @maio290 can you paste solution for this?

Comment: @fjsv in my functional class there was try and catch blocks

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `mockito.when()` is not working properly, since it looks like it is not throwing the exception you are asking it to throw. I had similar issues and *tinkering* with mockito matchers usually fixes them.

You can check [this page](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers) for a bit more information regarding "expanding" or restricting your argument matchers.

I think the solution bellow will work:

```
when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Mockito.any(JsonNode.class)))
    .thenThrow(e);
```